# Plotting two smooth terms from different GAM's on a single plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam

Is it possible to display smooth terms from different GAM's in R if those terms are estimated using the same form of data?

I have two ecological datasets with values of species diversity along an elevational gradient. One site ranges from 1700-2800 m a.s.l. while the other ranges from 2500-3800 m a.s.l. I've modelled the relationship of species diversity against elevation using `gam` in R and I would like to display the smooth term from each site's GAM in the same plot area. Something like this:

[image]

I know you can use `compare_smooths` to compare smooths between two GAMs but I was wondering if there was a more versatile approach.

Hopefully this question is fine without reproducible data.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create predictions from the two models covering the elevational ranges you want, and then plot the fitted values.

For example (code not checked as I am AFK right now)

```r
library("gratia")
library("dplyr")

newd <- data.frame(Elevation = c(seq(1700, 2800, length = 100), 
                                 seq(2500, 3800, length = 100)),
                   Site = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 100))
fv1 <- fitted_values(gam1, data = filter(newd, Site == "A"),
                     type = "response")
fv2 <- fitted_values(gam2, data = filter(newd, Site == "B"),
                     type = "response")
fv <- bind_rows(fv1, fv2)
```

Then you should have enough data in `fv` to plot, say

```r
library("ggplot2")

fv %>% ggplot(aes(x = Elevation, colour = Site)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = fitted)) +
  geom_point(data = foo, aes(x = Elevation, y = Diversity))
```

(where the last line is for adding the raw data, but I'm not sure how you have this arranged, so figure that bit out for yourself.)